# how to start tmux with custom layout?

Tags: tmux

In most of time, I start tmux with 3 panes, and each time I need create 3 panes mannually and refactor their location, is there any methods that can start new session with custom layout?

I've tried to solve my condition with [Tmux tile layout arranges 8 panes into 3x3 instead of 4x2](https://superuser.com/questions/1803835/tmux-tile-layout-arranges-8-panes-into-3x3-instead-of-4x2), but it return

```
❯ tmux select-layout "$(cat my_layout)" s
no server running on /private/tmp/tmux-501/default
```

what should I do?